# how to return data in a nesting function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to return function after check user existed and not existed

```
   var data = checkUser();
    alert(data);
```

// return a data after check user

```
function checkUser(){
$.ajax({
  type : "get",
  url : "checkuser",
  data : {
     username : username,
 },
 success: function(){
  return "ok";
 },
 error : function(){
  return "error";
 }
});
}
```

Comment: You can't return from an asynchronous function.

Comment: i want return ok/ error string checkUser function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to use [callback](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp) in this scenario:

```
 var myCallback = function(data){
   alert(data);
 };

 checkUser(myCallback);
```

Your ajax would be :

```
function checkUser(callback){
$.ajax({
  type : "get",
  url : "checkuser",
  data : {
     username : username,
 },
 success: function(){
   callback("ok");
 },
 error : function(){
  callback("error");
 }
});
}
```

Kindly read more on [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `async` and `await` if your nested function is an asynchronous function.
One way is to do this:

```
async function checkUser(){
    try {
       const result = await fetch("checkuser",{data:username});
       alert("ok");
    } catch (err) {
       alert("error");
    }

}
```